# UIImageView auto resizes when UIScrollView tapped

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview

Ok, so I have a UIImageView inside UIScrollView. I dynamically load an image into UIImageView and then manually resize it. So far so good. But then, if I touch UIScroll scroll view (containing resized elements) everything is resized back to the original size. Just in case, here's the code that resizes the image:

```
 /**
* Proportionally resize and position doodle
*/
- (void)resizeDoodle:(CGFloat)height {

self.doodleImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, height);
[self.scrollView setContentSize:self.doodleImageView.frame.size];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.Imageview.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

And This line keep image to fit

```
self.Imageview.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Write above code for restrict your issue.

**Another way:**

Use following method for specific **hight** and **width** (*That you want*) with **image**

```
+ (UIImage*)resizeImage:(UIImage*)image withWidth:(int)width withHeight:(int)height
{
    CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
    float widthRatio = newSize.width/image.size.width;
    float heightRatio = newSize.height/image.size.height;

    if(widthRatio > heightRatio)
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*heightRatio,image.size.height*heightRatio);
    }
    else
    {
        newSize=CGSizeMake(image.size.width*widthRatio,image.size.height*widthRatio);
    }


    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
    UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

This method return **NewImage**, with specific size that you specify :)
This code may be helpful for you:)

Comment: thanks for your response. This did force the image to resize proportionally but didn't solve my issue. The image still went back to the original size after I tried scrolling UIScrollView.

Comment: thanks. I can certainly resize the image but for some reason it scales back after I scroll. I have no idea why it does that especially after it has been successfully resized.

Comment: self.View.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;...please use this code for your view

Comment: @AndreiTaraschuk may be Autolayout needs to be disabled for that viewcomponent.As Autolayout forces it to resize back to same size.